# wp_enqueue wont work on some files?

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-script

So if i use the following in functions.php in the root off my child folder it works as supposed:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_my_scripts');
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'checkboxCheckAll');
//register_scripts
function register_my_scripts(){

wp_register_script('checkboxCheckAll', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/Lib/dynamic-table/jsScripts/checkboxCheckAll.js');
}

//enqueue_scripts
function enqueue_my_scripts(){
wp_enqueue_script('checkboxCheckAll');
}
```

now i have a custom page with the following code:

```
<?php /* Template Name: vagter-flex */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>


    <div class="x-main full" role="main">

      <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
          <div class="entry-wrap">

            <?php x_get_view( 'global', '_content', 'the-content' ); ?>
            <?php require('Lib/dynamic-table/functions.php');?>
          </div>
        </article>

      <?php endwhile; ?>

    </div>


<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

now this page also loads a file called functions.php and if i try to enqueue the script with the same code as above its not working, there is no errors displayed and simply nothing happens?

and just to make it clear yes i am on the custom page when i try to use the script

Comment: where is the custom page template? if it is not in the theme root it might not be finding `header.php` which (should) call `wp_head`

Comment: `function enqueue_my_scripts()` should be  `function checkboxCheckAll()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't how `functions.php` works in WordPress.

The `functions.php` in your theme root directory is loaded into WordPress environment by default as long as your theme is activated. It's used as a plugin to add features and functionality of your theme to WordPress. You should take a look at [theme functions](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/) and [including css & javascript](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/including-css-javascript/#enqueuing-scripts-and-styles) for more info.

Besides that, the [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) hook is fired inside the [get_header()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/) which happens before you can `require('Lib/dynamic-table/functions.php')`.

You can fix that by `require('Lib/dynamic-table/functions.php')` inside the `functions.php` in theme root directory.

Comment: thanks for the informative answer if i could vote it up i would :)

Comment: @Alexander No problem. Glad I could help ;-)